# MVC6 Self-Hosted wwwroot content returns 404, IIS Express doesn't

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm playing with ASP.NET5/MVC6 and I built a small web application. When I use the IIS Express debug server of Visual Studio, everything is working as expected. But when I use the "web" server profile, meaning the WebListener server, then only my MVC Controllers and Views work. However, everything stored under "wwwroot" returns a 404. What I've put there are the CSS, JS and image files.

As soon as I switch back to IIS Express, the content is fetched properly.

The full source code is available there: https://github.com/acastaner/acastaner.fr-mvc6

This is my Startup class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
```

This is my project.json file:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": { },
        "aspnetcore50": { }
    },
    "bundleExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "commands": {
        "web ": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
    }
}
```

I'm using Razor for the views, here's a sample of how I reference the files:

```
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Is there something obvious that I totally missed?

Edit:

I did try using `@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.min.css")` but the effect is the same.

Comment: I don't think IIS is hooked up yet. I think you have to go with IIS Express for now whilst VS is still in CTP

Comment: But I'm trying to use self-hosting (ie: application starts as a console), not IIS?

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem as you... Only with an unmodified (literally) MVC 6 Web Site Preview Project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060193/deploy-visual-studio-web-app-to-iis-maybe-even-azure-continuous-deployment-git

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need one more dependency: `"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3"` and `app.UseStaticFiles();` before `app.UseMvc`

Comment: That was it, thanks! (sorry for the delay in validating your answer, I was traveling)