# Deploy Visual Studio Web App to IIS (Maybe Even Azure Continuous Deployment Git)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy my MVC 6 Web App from VS 2015 RC. I am using IIS 7.5. I have browsed other user's questions regarding similar deployments, but their solutions haven't worked for me...

Specifically, I am following this guide (unsuccessfully): http://dotnetspeak.com/2015/03/publish-asp-net-v-next-to-iis

I am literally just trying to publish the default .NET 5/MVC 6 Visual Studio Web App... Below is a detailed account of what I have tried. No idea what I'm doing wrong. I admit, I am very rusty with IIS and .NET. So please keep that in mind!

---

### Visual Studio 2015 Web Publish

The author tells you to:

> Right click on Default Web Site and choose Add  Application

#### So the values I used during 'Publish Web':

- Profile Name: ***DerekFoulk.com***
- Target Location: ***c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DerekFoulk.com***
- Configuration: ***Release***
- Target DNX Version: ***Default (dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4)***
- Publish Scripts: ***Publish using PowerShell script***

I then saw:

> Your application will be published to:
>
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DerekFoulk.com

So I clicked **Publish**

---

### Adding to IIS 7.5

Before I did this, I noticed that there was already an entry in IIS that was titled the same name as my Project. Could this be due to the fact I have been using the default 'Start Debugging - IIS Express' button to preview my app in my browser?

I then opened up IIS and right-clicked the **Default Web Site** and hit **Add Application**. I used the following configuration:

- Alias: ***DerekFoulk***
- Application pool: ***DefaultAppPool***
- Physical path: ***C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DerekFoulk.com\wwwroot***
- Pass-through authentication

I then hit **Test Settings** and got the following error message:

> There was an error while performing this operation.
>
> Details:
>
> Invalid application path

The author didn't mention checking the settings, and even though I knew this would mean things wouldn't work right, I hit **OK**.

Finally, the author says to:

> Go to security in windows explorer under TestApp folder.  Add **Authenticated Users** group account and give it read and execute rights.

So I right-clicked the directory (**C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DerekFoulk.com**) and went to **Properties > Security** and did not see the Authenticated Users group. I did, however, see that **IIS_IUSRS** had **Read & execute** permission. I figured these were appropriate permissions, and continued to try to view my app in the browser...

I navigated to **http://localhost/DerekFoulk/**. It shows the following error on the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/DerekFoulk' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Assembly Load Trace:</b> The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' could not be loaded.<br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &#39;dnx.clr.managed&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

[TypeLoadException: The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +556

[HttpException (0x80004005): The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +726
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.57.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[FileNotFoundException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;dnx.clr.managed&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateAppDomainManager()
[TypeLoadException]: The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated.
   at System.AppDomain.CreateAppDomainManager()
   at System.AppDomain.Setup(Object arg)
   at System.AppDomain.nCreateDomain(String friendlyName, AppDomainSetup setup, Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo, IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor)
   at System.AppDomain.InternalCreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateDomain(String friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info)
   at AspNet.Loader.Bootstrapper.LoadApplicationNet45(String appId, String appConfigPath, IProcessHostSupportFunctions supportFunctions, LoadApplicationData* pLoadAppData, Int32 loadAppDataSize, String runtimePackagePath, String appBasePath)
   at AspNet.Loader.Bootstrapper.LoadApplication(String appId, String appConfigPath, IProcessHostSupportFunctions supportFunctions, LoadApplicationData* pLoadAppData, Int32 loadAppDataSize)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostLite.ReportCustomLoaderError(String appId, Int32 hr, AppDomain newlyCreatedAppDomain)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
[HttpException]: The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated.
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
-->
```

The snippet above has some details on the error at the bottom of the page, but I can't interpret them...

I don't think the publishing is the problem. I think I am doing something wrong in IIS... Anyways, any advice on how to publish an MVC 6 app to local IIS would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

## Update

Interesting observation... I tried to deploy to Microsoft Azure as a Web App by following these instructions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso-git/

The app builds great on my local machine with no errors, but when I tried to deploy to Azure using the Git/Team Services integration, I received the following error:

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

span {
  color: #c00;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
Build started 6/25/2015 9:50:58 PM.<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1>Project "C:\a\src\DerekFoulk.sln" on node 1 (default targets).<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1>Project "C:\a\src\DerekFoulk.sln" (1) is building "C:\a\src\src\DerekFoulk\DerekFoulk.xproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2>PrepareForBuild:<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Creating directory "..\..\artifacts\obj\DerekFoulk\Debug\".<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PreComputeCompileTypeScript:<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\tsc.exe  --noEmitOnError COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CompileTypeScript:<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Skipping target "CompileTypeScript" because it has no outputs.<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;GetRuntimeToolingPathTarget:<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4 in the folder: C:\Users\buildguest\.dnx\runtimes</span><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets(117,5): error : The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details. [C:\a\src\src\DerekFoulk\DerekFoulk.xproj]<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2>Done Building Project "C:\a\src\src\DerekFoulk\DerekFoulk.xproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1>Done Building Project "C:\a\src\DerekFoulk.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.<br>
<br>
Build FAILED.<br>
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"C:\a\src\DerekFoulk.sln" (default target) (1) -><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"C:\a\src\src\DerekFoulk\DerekFoulk.xproj" (default target) (2) -><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(GetRuntimeToolingPathTarget target) -> <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets(117,5): error : The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details. [C:\a\src\src\DerekFoulk\DerekFoulk.xproj]<br>
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;0 Warning(s)<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;1 Error(s)<br>
<br>
Time Elapsed 00:00:10.40<br>
```

So I can't do anything with a default .NET 5/MVC 6 Web App? Literally, I can only preview it?

---

## Update

I was able to publish the site to Azure as a Web App using **Build > Publish > Microsoft Azure Web Apps**, but even after deleting everything and starting from scratch, I cannot get **Continuous Deployment from Source Control (Git) / Visual Studio Team Services** to deploy. The build fails, still saying

> Build
>   (-1, 0)
>   Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
>   Exception Stack Trace: at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets (117, 0)
>   The Dnx Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details.

Has anyone been able to setup continuous deployment via Git/Visual Studio Team Services? If so, how?!

---

## Update (Continuous Build from Git/Team Services)

So the following may be the issue when the build fails:

> Now we can build the solution. Since the default web template targets both the full .NET and .NET Core, we expect the build to fail when it tries to access the Environment.MachineName and Environment.OSVersion variables in HomeController. This behavior won’t work in .NET Core (currently), so we can comment it out. Open project.json and modify the “frameworks” key as shown:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }/*,
    "dnxcore50": { }*/
},
```

---

## Update

Here are the log files from the failed build:
[OneDrive - Log Files](http://1drv.ms/1BG80vY)
Hopefully someone sees this and can help me crack the problem so that my site will deploy to Azure when I push a commit. It would be great during development!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deployment process is explained [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html). Take a few minutes to read the links in the posts that touch on changes to the hosting model for .NET apps on IIS.

After ensuring that I had the right .NET version installed on my server (I used [DNVM](https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm)), I was able to get my app up and running on my local IIS machine.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell, but perhaps due to your target publish path and IIS app physical path not matching...

Target Location: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DerekFoulk.com

vs.

Physical path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DerekFoulk.com\wwwroot

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. The guy who wrote the tutorial referenced this directory specifically and commented on making sure to use this path. I have learned that there are different requirements for "Web Sites" and "Web Apps" now. Back in the day, you copied your site's directory to inetpub & created a new site in IIS (straightforward) and ensured there was an 'index.*' or 'Default.*' file. Done deal. Not with these new apps though (I think). I will play around with that location some more and see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will help specifically with the DnxRuntime issue.

When VS Team Services builds it needs all the stuff that we use to build on dev PCs.

Basically, you create a prebuild script that downloads dnvm, installs it and finally calls dnu restore for each of your project.json files. Works best of you have all your code in a src subdirectory and have a global.json file.

I based my solution on this article where you can find the script: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5

Comment: Following the link above, I have managed to get a continuous build going for an Asp.Net 5 site on Azure. I spent quite a bit of time failing and messing around before I resorted to pretty much following the link to the letter (which worked). I am still getting locks on file during deployment so may have to stop/start the service during deployment. Don't care right now though :-)

Comment: Thanks for the resource! I will take a peek and see if this resolves my issue. If so, I will mark this as the answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post, and I hope my answer helps someone.  I ran into the same error as the poster regarding "Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies."  I hadn't noticed that Enable 32-Bit Applications was set to "False" in my application pool.  Setting it to "True" solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to deploying to Azure:

As mentioned by Danie Sharpe there is https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5 which I got working. The one change I needed to make I mention in my answer to this question [Build ASP.NET 5 to Azure websites from Visual Studio Online ERROR_FILE_IN_USE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106100/build-asp-net-5-to-azure-websites-from-visual-studio-online-error-file-in-use/32177326#32177326).

A slightly different route is not using the Visual Studio Publish (on VS Team Services) but instead the DNU publish command. I go through that in quite a lot of detail in a blog post which you can find here: http://devonburriss.me/aspnet-vsonline-ci/

Let us know how you get on. Looks like you have spent quite a bit of time on this already.